# Problems with repainting JPanel Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I ran into an element rendering issue.
However, not everything is so clear.
Some monitors render correctly.

For example, I have a laptop with a Full HD display and a 2K monitor.
On a laptop, the rendering is always correct, but there are problems on the 2K monitor (see the videos below).

Also, if I hide the application on a 2K monitor and then expand it, the block is displayed correctly.

```
 public class Block extends JPanel implements DragGestureListener {

    private int[][] currentBlockMatrix;
    private Color currentColor;

    Block() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 180, 180);
        this.setLayout(null);
        var ds = new DragSource();
        ds.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY, this);
    }


    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        currentBlockMatrix = RandomGenerator.getRandomBlockMatrix();
        currentColor = RandomGenerator.getRandomColor();

        boolean firstFilled = false;

        graphics.setColor(currentColor);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (currentBlockMatrix[i][j] == 1) {
                    graphics.fillRect(j * 46, i * 46, 46, 46);
                    if (!firstFilled) {
                        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
                        graphics.fillOval(j * 46 + 18, i * 46 + 18, 10, 10);
                        graphics.setColor(currentColor);
                        firstFilled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
        var cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();

        if (dge.getDragAction() == DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY) {
            cursor = DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop;
        }

        dge.startDrag(cursor, new TransferablePanel(currentColor, currentBlockMatrix));
    }
}
```

Instance of Block class repaints everytime the figure drops on the grid

Demonstration of work on the full hd monitor:
https://youtu.be/posZ1XZAHUQ

Demonstration of work on the 2K monitor:
https://youtu.be/3tGjGYjGVY8

Comment: Moral of the story - don't use null layouts. Learn to use layout managers

Comment: @g00se how do you think, what layout would be best?

Comment: There is no such thing as one best layout. Best to learn the major ones first, BorderLayout, GridLayout, FlowLayout, BoxLayout, and then the more difficult ones, GridBagLayout, SpringLayout, and perhaps GroupLayout, and then nest JPanels, each using its own layout, to achieve simple, yet flexible and stable GUI's.

Comment: Usually, when you override method `paintComponent`, the first line in the method is a call to the superclass method, i.e. `super.paintComponent(graphics)`

Comment: You could probably get away with just a `BorderLayout` for that. Your grid could be placed on one `JPanel` and controls could be placed on another `JPanel`. You might set the preferred size of one to get that somewhat unequal width distribution. If you wanted to be adventurous about it, you could use a `GridBagLayout`